# Add dates from one column to another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have a pandas dataframe with multiple IDs and with other columns I have two date columns say : 'date1' and 'date2'. I want to add the dates from second column to the first. This has to be done for within the same IDs in the dataframe.

What I have:

```
ID   date1     date2       value
1    1/1/2013  5/1/2013    a
1    4/1/2013  16/1/2013   a
1    8/3/2014  31/12/2014  b
2    11/4/2013  15/5/2013  a
2    19/5/2016  18/1/2017  b
2    8/4/2017  18/5/2017   b
```

The output I want :

```
ID   date1      value
1    1/1/2013   a
1    5/1/2013   a
1    4/1/2013   a
1    16/1/2013  a
1    8/3/2014   b
1    31/12/2014 b
2    11/4/2013  a
2    15/5/2013  a
2    19/5/2016  b
2    18/1/2017  b
2    8/4/2017   b
2    18/5/2017  b
```

Thank you.

Comment: you need `.melt` see duplicate question for more info and visit the docs for melt [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can melt the dataframe:

```
df.melt(value_vars=['date1', 'date2'])

   variable       value
0     date1    1/1/2013
1     date1    4/1/2013
2     date1    8/3/2014
3     date1   11/4/2013
4     date1   19/5/2016
5     date1    8/4/2017
6     date2    5/1/2013
7     date2   16/1/2013
8     date2  31/12/2014
9     date2   15/5/2013
10    date2   18/1/2017
11    date2   18/5/2017
```

To set the ID and so on:

```
df.rename(columns={'value': 'val'}).melt(id_vars=['ID', 'val'], value_vars=['date1', 'date2']).drop('variable', axis=1).set_index('ID')

ID
1     1/1/2013
1     4/1/2013
1     8/3/2014
2    11/4/2013
2    19/5/2016
2     8/4/2017
1     5/1/2013
1    16/1/2013
1   31/12/2014
2    15/5/2013
2    18/1/2017
2    18/5/2017
```

Comment: I have updated my question. This is where I was having problem with melt.

Comment: @yellow_smile adjusted second part of my answer

Comment: This worked. Though no need to use rename. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most straightforward way of doing it in this example:

```
df.set_index('ID',inplace=True)
```

and then:

```
df2 = df.date1.append(df.date2).to_frame('date1')
```

which will just stack the two columns together.

More generally if you have more than 2 columns you'd like to stack, you could do something like:

```
columns_to_stack = ['date1','date2']
final_name = 'date1'
df3 = pd.concat(
    df[column] for column in columns_to_stack
).to_frame(final_name)
```

wherein you can define as many columns to stack up as you like, and provide the name you'd like applied to the end result.